# Include file in Apache2 EnvVars File?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-1.3

Greetings Fellow Admins,

I just read that I can put environment variables in (for RedHat) in /etc/sysconfig/httpd

My question is, how do I include a file from that file

I ask this because I would like to put all my config files under version control, and the idea as of now is to have webhead specific variables inside a file like web04.conf and then on web04, create a symlink (git ignored) webhead.conf that points to web04.conf and include webhead.conf inside /etc/sysconfig/httpd

Any ideas on this setup are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, you can include another file by

```
. /<directory>/<filename>
```